# Mistakenly added service worker. Removed it but how to get it off existing computers?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

When starting an Angular (6) project, i used a template that had a service worker. Several months later, i had a problem that the solution was to remove the service worker (via removing `ServiceWorkerModule.register` from my app.module imports). However, every computer that opened that app prior to that version still has the service worker installed and running (still causing the original issue). I know I can manually remove one on one computer via dev-tools, but how can I get a solution in code?

Some Things I've tried:

- https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#fail-safe This says you can remove your `ngsw.json` file and the service worker will "self destruct" but our running code's root folder doesn't have a `ngsw.json`, only a `ngsw-config.json`. Also says you can rename `safety-worker.js` to the name of your old service worker but my deployed code doesn't have `safety-worker.js` nor do i know the name of my service worker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'unregister' the service worker using javascript. Here is an example:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
        //returns installed service workers
        if (registrations.length) {
          for(let registration of registrations) {
            registration.unregister();
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: So where in angular do you add startup js like that? `ngOnInit` in app.component?

Comment: You can add this in your index.html file.

Comment: or at the head of your angular file (app.component.ts)